# Spring @Resource annotation is not working

Tags: spring, annotations, dependencies, resources, code-injection

I'm studying about spring framework DI.

The Register object is injected with a KeywordDao object. `@Autowired` annotation works fine with the constructor. However, if I use `@Resource` annotation for the Field, it will not work(null).

javax.annotation-api dependency was added as Maven because `@Resource` was not imported.

Below is the source code.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

...

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jeongyongs</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-injection</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

...

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="keywordDao" class="com.jeongyongs.keyword.KeywordDao"/>
    <bean id="register" class="com.jeongyongs.keyword.Register"/>

</beans>
```

KeywordDao.java:

```
package com.jeongyongs.keyword;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class KeywordDao {
    private Map<String, String> db = new HashMap<>();

    public void insert(String key, String value) {
        db.put(key, value);
    }

    public String select(String key) {
        return db.get(key);
    }

    public void update(String key, String value) {
        db.replace(key, value);
    }

    public void delete(String key) {
        db.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Register.java:

```
package com.jeongyongs.keyword;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class Register {

    @Resource
    private KeywordDao keywordDao;

    public void newKeyword(String key, String value) {
        if (isAvailable(key)) {
            keywordDao.insert(key, value);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("REG: fail! invalid key value.");
    }

    private boolean isAvailable(String key) {
        return keywordDao.select(key) == null;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.jeongyongs.keyword;

import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String context = "classpath:applicationContext.xml";
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(context);
        Register register = ctx.getBean("register", Register.class);

        register.newKeyword("New key", "New value");
        register.newKeyword("New key", "New value");

        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.jeongyongs.keyword.KeywordDao.select(String)" because "this.keywordDao" is null
    at com.jeongyongs.keyword.Register.isAvailable(Register.java:21)
    at com.jeongyongs.keyword.Register.newKeyword(Register.java:11)
    at com.jeongyongs.keyword.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

I tried to use `@Resource(name="keywordDao")` but not working.

I want to try DI with `@Resource` annotation. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved with this:**
I realized that there is no working codes for `@Resource` annotation.
So, I thought I didn't bring in all the necessary dependencies.
As a result, I changed pom.xml and fixed the problem.

**From:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**To:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using an old unsupported dependency from the JavaEE era whereas you should have used the JakartaEE one from the start (or not use `@Resource` at all and just use `@Autowired` instead).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks to this, I was able to learn about Java EE and Jakarta EE. I used `@Resource` for studying, but if I work on a real project, I think I will use `@Autowired`. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: If you use constructor injection (which is preferable over field injection) you don't need either.